# Authentication, O Auth 2, Google Cloud Platform COS Container Optimized

Tags: docker, google-cloud-platform, oauth-2.0, google-oauth

I have created a GCP instance using Container Optimized "COS" Linux on Google Cloud. The instance also pulls from the Docker repo, and hosts several containers at startup. The machine spins up fine, and the instances are live. Absolutely no errors.

The problem comes when I try to access it from the outside using https://www.googleapis.com/../..

I get the following error (in any browser):

```
    {
  "error": {
    "code": 401,
    "message": "Request is missing required authentication credential. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential. See https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project.",
    "errors": [
      {
        "message": "Login Required.",
        "domain": "global",
        "reason": "required",
        "location": "Authorization",
        "locationType": "header"
      }
    ],
    "status": "UNAUTHENTICATED"
  }
}
```

I have worked with GCP for years and never seen this error. I have just started using COS though. I am thinking that it may be related to that? Any hints?

Comment: The `OAuth 2` is initiated by the APIs. Check this [link](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/openid-connect#sendauthrequest). You need to share more details on the APIs that you are using and how are they related to the application in the container

Comment: Please edit your question and include your code

Comment: What is the full api call that you perform to get this error?

Answer (score 0):

In GCE the default access scope to the Storage API is Read Only and, since your instance pulls from the Docker Registry, the Service Account you are using needs to have one of the following scopes:

- Read/Write (https://www.googleapis.com/auth/devstorage.read_write)
- Full Control (https://www.googleapis.com/auth/devstorage.full_control)

You can check and edit the instance's API scopes in the Cloud Console inside the instance details, or in the Cloud Shell using these commands:

- List access scopes: `curl "http://metadata.google.internal/computeMetadata/v1/instance/service-accounts/?recursive=true" -H "Metadata-Flavor: Google"`
- Add scopes: `gcloud alpha compute instances [INSTANCE_NAME] --scopes=[SCOPE,...] --service-account=[SERVICE_ACCOUNT]`. Replace [SCOPE] with `storage-rw` (Read/Write) or `storage-full` (Full Control).